# Does CSS file affect styles of HTML elements embedded through iFrame

Tags: html, css

If I embed a html file into my index.html file, would my external CSS file affect elements, say a `<div class="br">` in the file I embedded?

Say I have these styles in the CSS file

```
.br {
position: fixed;
width: 101%;
left: -1%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Because I have an element with a class of br in the index.html file that needs the same styles.

The embedded file also contains `<div class="br">`
My question: does the CSS file affect the elements in the embedded file?

If yes, which is better: `<embed>` or `<iframe>< iframe>`?

Comment: It will not affect the iframe content.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

> No

```
<iframe>
```

The iframe element represents a nested browsing context. HTML 5 standard - "The `<iframe>` element"
Primarily used to include resources from other domains or subdomains but can be used to include content from the same domain as well. The `<iframe>`'s strength is that the embedded code is 'live' and can communicate with the parent document.

```
<embed>
```

embed is ideal to get the visitor to follow a redirect chain originating at a website that blocks framing

Unless you are embedding SVG or something static you are probably best of using `<iframe>`. To include SVG use embed (if I remember correctly  won't let you script).

Comment: Yeah, thought so, was just making sure. Thanks